# Printing to stdout returning gibbersih

Tags: c

I am using gcc 10.1.1 on Fedora 32.
The following program is to read from a file given by the user and print it into stdout. The code is an example in Modern C by Jens Gusdets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

enum { buf_max = 32,};

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc +1]){
  int ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
  char buffer[buf_max] = {0};
  for(int i = 0; i<argc ; ++i){
    FILE* instream = fopen(argv[i] , "r");
    if(instream){
      while(fgets(buffer , buf_max , instream)){
        fputs(buffer, stdout);
     }
      fclose(instream);
      ret = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: ", argv[i]);
      perror(0);
      errno = 0;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

But when I run the program it is printing some gibberish like :

```
$ ./read some.txt
ELFDib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2Co.6locationderrGLIBC_2.2.5@@@/��^H��H���PTI��@@H=X@@�H��H�H��t�f.��z������UH��H��@�}�H�u��E����`..��������ATA��UH�-T+t1��u�H�[]A\A]A^A_�ff.������A�C
G@n8A0A(B BB���oGCC: (GNU) 10.1.1 20200507 (Red Hat 10.1.1-1)�@�@�@�@�@�@�@�@1�@ gcc 10.1.1 2020050730k_clashectionYSSERTIONSGA!stack_realign�@ gcc 10.1.1 2020050730k_cl@Z�@@nux/10/../../../../lib64/crt1.oc_endbin_init.c_end.hott.c.unlikelyd.unlikelytupinit.c_end.exit_reloc.cc_endothotikelynd.unlikelyoc.c.startuploc.c_end.startupic_reloc.c.exit_reloc.c_end.exitrelocate_static_pie.startbin__dl_relocate_static_pie.endsed.0_array_entrye_dummy_init_array_entry__FRAME_END___DYNAMICNU_EH_FRAME_HDRTABLE_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5LIBC_2.2.5_2.2.5c_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5@@GLIBC_2.2.5ntf@@GLIBC_2.2.5libc_csu_initic_pieGLIBC_2.2.55nterpABI-tagtr.rela.dynh_framebsstesuh @�?@0yey my c program worked.
```

some.txt = yey my c program worked.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[argc +1]) { ... }` is equivalent to `int main(int argc, char *argv[420]) { ... }` is equivalent to `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }` is equivalent to the `int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }`. I'd stick with one of the last 2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[0]` is always the program name. You're printing the contents of your executable in addition to any extra files identified by the filenames passed in the arguments by starting your `for` loop at `i = 0`.

If you start at `i = 1`, it will exclude your executable.